# Object detection using turicreate

Tags: python-3.x, turi

I was exploring turicreate ObjectDetector API. The documentation mentions it is a trained model. I wanted to know if I can use this trained model & detect the 1000 labels which was used to originally train this turi model. All the examples mention to train with our dataset, I do not want to train but wanted to use pre-trained model which can classify. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question about how to load and use a pre-trained model? [Turi create API docs](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/api/turicreate.load_model.html) mentions a `load_model` method:

```
model.save('my_model_file')
loaded_model = tc.load_model('my_model_file')
```

EDIT: Yep, `ObjectDetector` exposes a [`save`](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/api/generated/turicreate.object_detector.ObjectDetector.save.html#turicreate.object_detector.ObjectDetector.save) method that works well with `load_model`.

Comment: What I am asking is how to get the pre trained turi models . Apple only releases pre trained CoreMl model , I wanted to know how can we get the pre trained turi models: https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/models/